# Escopo de Objetos Literais - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estava fazendo uns teste aqui, e percebi uma diferença no `this` dentro de objetos literais:

```
obj = {
    context: this,
    showContext: function(){ return this }
}
```

Se eu fizer `pessoa.context` o `this` vai apontar para o objeto `window`, mas se eu fizer `pessoa.showContext()`  o `this` retornado vai apontar para o objeto `obj` e não para a função `showContext`. Alguém sabe o motivo desse comportamento?

Comment: [Na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) tem vários exemplos explicando isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando declaras o objeto o valor que é atribuído a `.context` é `this` que é o contexto de execução desse código, ou seja provavelmente `window`.

Ou seja, o mesmo que fazeres:

```
var foo = this;
obj = {
    context: foo,
```

Quando corres a função ela faz parte do objeto e por definição (sem ser em `strict mode`) o `this` retorna o objeto que é pai da função como contexto de execução.

Assim apesar de usares `this` em ambos eles são bem diferentes. O primeiro é interpretado imediatamente no momento de atribuição do valor de `.context` (ou seja quando o objeto é criado), o segundo é chamado/avaliado no momento de execução da função.

Answer (score 0):

isto acontece porque `obj` foi declarado dentro de `window`, ou seja:

```
obj = {};
```

é o mesmo que

```
window.obj = {};
```

no entanto, o teu `showContext` foi delcarado com um function statement,  então ele ganha o scope de onde foi criado - neste caso: `obj` (que por sua vez está no scope de window)